# Getting progress view to update

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I have been trying to get my progress view to update, but most of the questions have been about using progress view as a timer. Instead, I am running a for loop a couple thousand times and it takes a little why. I want the use to know how far along the method is, so I've implemented a progress view like this (there is a bunch of other stuff in the for loop but I don't think it is necessary to answer my question):

```
for i in 0..<2429 {
        var progress = Double(i) / Double(2430)
        print(progress)
        seasonProgress.setProgress(Float(progress), animated: false)
        seasonProgress.reloadInputViews()   
}
```

When I print `progress` is it updating with every loop, but the progress view (name `seasonProgress`) only updates after the for loop is complete. How do I get it to upload while the for loop is going? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: No need for `reloadInputViews()`.
make sure you run it on MainThread

Comment: Your loop is blocking the main queue until it completes. Do not block the main queue as you perform some long running process.

Comment: I'm sorta new to this, what does it mean to block the main queue? and how do I avoid that?